# Programmatically get the URL Scheme from plist, from within a today extension

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, info.plist, today-extension

Ultimately I'm trying to launch the Main app from the Widget by doing

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("MyURLScheme//"));
```

So I have an iOS application with a today extension.  I would like to access my main application's URL Scheme.  Is that possible?  My URL Scheme is inside my Plist file of my main application and not my today extension.  Can I just reference the one from the main app?  I tried getting it from CFBundleURLTypes and CFBundleURLSchemes but they both turn up as "null". 
 Probably because it's looking in the widget's Plist and not the main app's Plist.

```
var asdf2 = NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary["CFBundleURLTypes"];
var asdf3 = NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary["CFBundleURLSchemes"];
```

Here is a screenshot of where the URL Scheme is located in the main app's Plist file.  I'd prefer to not have to store duplicate information in the today extension's Plist file.  And I'd also prefer to not have to hardcode the URL Scheme into the today extension's code.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can refer below URL
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56324673)

```
extension Bundle {

 static let externalURLSchemes: [String] = {
    guard let urlTypes = main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleURLTypes"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
        return []
    }

    var result: [String] = []
    for urlTypeDictionary in urlTypes {
        guard let urlSchemes = urlTypeDictionary["CFBundleURLSchemes"] as? [String] else { continue }
        guard let externalURLScheme = urlSchemes.first else { continue }
        result.append(externalURLScheme)
    }

    return result
 }()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

would be something (ugly) like this :

```
var arr = (NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary["CFBundleURLTypes"] as NSMutableArray);
var urlTypes = arr.GetItem<NSDictionary>(0);
var schemes = urlTypes.ObjectForKey(new NSString("CFBundleURLSchemes")) as NSMutableArray;
var scheme = schemes.GetItem<NSString>(0).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create an `App Group` for your app and your extension which will allow you to place a plist or any other file for that matter that you want to share between the 2 into a shared location on disk.

Here's an article that explains how this is done:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#configure-an-app-group

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Bundle {
    static let externalURLSchemes: [String] = {
        guard let urlTypes = main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleURLTypes"] as? [[String: Any]],
              let urlSchemesDictionary = urlTypes.first(where: { $0["CFBundleURLSchemes"] != nil }),
              let urlSchemes = urlSchemesDictionary["CFBundleURLSchemes"] as? [String]
        else {
            return []
        }
        return urlSchemes
    }()
}
```